# UI Bootstrap typeahed clear $viewValue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the UI Bootstrap `typeahead` on an `input` to act as a searchable dropdown menu.

I have a clear button that should reset the `input` and that works fine (by resetting the model) as long as I don't use `typeahead-editable="false"`.

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/399HT89ZxiG9APYMVNwN?p=preview) that illustrates the problem:

1. Enter an invalid input, for example 'xzy'
2. Press outside of the `input`
3. Press clear
4. The `input` isn't cleared

Is this the intented functionality? Should I enter a valid value, then that value is cleared.